# Postgres. Read-only mode

Tags: postgresql

I have an archive database. I want to set a parameter for it default_transaction_read_only = ON. I have a function that removes read-only mode.

```
create or replace procedure tmp_util_archive_set_db_read_only(IN pisreadlonly boolean)
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
 SET default_transaction_read_only to OFF;
 if pIsReadlOnly then
  ALTER database mpbr SET default_transaction_read_only to ON;
 elseif not(pIsReadlOnly) then
  set transaction read write;
  ALTER database mpbr SET default_transaction_read_only to OFF;
 end if;
end
$$;
```

But when I call it I get an error

```
cannot execute ALTER DATABASE in a read-only transaction
```

Is it possible to use the function to bring the database out of read-only mode?

```
do
$$
    begin
        call tmp_util_archive_set_db_read_only(pisreadlonly := false);
    end
$$;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible inside a function. Additionally, your attempt has the problem that you are setting `default_transaction_read_only`, which only sets the default value, but does not change the current transaction. You'd have to set `transaction_read_only`, but that would result in

```
ERROR:  transaction read-write mode must be set before any query
```

The problem is that the `SELECT` statement that calls the function has already started executing in the current transaction, so it is too late to change the isolation.

You'll have to do it outside the function call:

```
START TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
SELECT tmp_util_archive_set_db_read_only(FALSE);
COMMIT;
```